# “ImportError: No module named core_rnn” When I use tensorflow and use the tflearn？

Tags: python, tensorflow

the program can be [downloaded](https://github.com/chrisruk/cnn) from:

The error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "/home/imatrix/download/ chrisruk/cnn-master/train_cnn.py", line 7, in  import tflearn
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/**init**.py",
>   line 21, in  from .layers import normalization   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/layers/**init**.py",
>   line 10, in  from .recurrent import lstm, gru, simple_rnn,
>   bidirectional_rnn, \    File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/layers/recurrent.py",
>   line 8, in    ImportError: No module named core_rnn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the error is because of **incompatible versions** of `tflearn` and `tensorflow`. (Probably you have updated `tflearn`, but didn't update `tensorflow`).

Try remove `tensorflow` and `tflearn` packages and install the latest version:

```
pip uninstall tflearn 
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install -I tensorflow
pip install -I tflearn
```

Or if you don't want to use `tensorflow v1.0` then install older versions of both packages:

```
pip uninstall tflearn 
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install -I tensorflow==0.12.1
pip install -I tflearn==0.2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Tf 0.12` onwards these have been moved to:

```
tf.contrib.rnn [followed by whichever core_rnn. you need ]
```